# jQuery removing appended elements at end of script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a segment of code that is supposed to put a text segment before each of some html elements. It does place them, and I have tested to see how far it does, but it removes them sometime after the function ends. Is this a problem with jQuery, or a problem with loading HTML from another document?

Here is the code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>DnD 4E Character Maker</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #Stats{
            width:100%;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
        }
        .half{
            text-align:center;
            width:50%;
            height:100px;
        }
        .reveal{
            width:100%
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id = "charsheet">
    Character Name:<input type="text" name = "name" value = "John Doe"></input>
    Level:<input type="text" name = "level" value = "1"></input>
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" value = "25"></input>

Race:
<select name = "race">
     <option value = "Dragonborn">Dragonborn</option>
     <option value = "Dwarf">Dwarf</option>
     <option value = "Eladrin">Eladrin</option>
     <option value = "Elf">Elf</option>
     <option value = "Half-Elf">Half-Elf</option>
     <option value = "Halfling">Halfling</option>
     <option value = "Human">Human</option>
     <option value = "Tiefling">Tiefling</option>
</select>

Class:
<select name = "class">
     <option value = "Cleric">Cleric</option>
     <option value = "Fighter">Fighter</option>
     <option value = "Paladin">Paladin</option>
     <option value = "Ranger">Ranger</option>
     <option value = "Rogue">Rogue</option>
     <option value = "Warlock">Warlock</option>
     <option value = "Warlord">Warlord</option>
     <option value = "Wizard">Wizard</option>
</select>
<select name = "generation">
    <option value = "standard">Standard (3d6-arranged)</option>
    <option value = "static">Static (3d6-ordered)</option>
    <option value = "pointbuy">PointBuy (Base 8, 25 points)</option>
    <option value = "array">Array (16-14-13-12-11-10)</option>
</select>
<input type = "button" value = "Submit" id = "sub">
</form>

<table class = "reveal">
<tr><td class = "Stats" colspan = "2"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td id = "Race" class = "half"></td>
<td id = "Class" class = "half"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
<script>
    $("#sub").click(function(){
        var x = $("#charsheet").serializeArray();
        var name = x[0].value;
        var level = x[1].value;
        var age = x[2].value;
        var race = x[3].value;
        var classes = x[4].value;
        jQuery.each(x, function(index, value){
            console.log(index + ":" + value.name + ":" + value.value);
        });
        $(".Stats").load('statsheet.html');
        $("#Race").text(race);
        $("#Class").text(classes);
        $(".reveal").css({
            'border-style':'ridge',
            'text-align':'center',
        });
        $(".half").css({
            'text-align':'center top',
            'width':'50%'
        });
        var statarray = ["str","con","dex","int","wis","cha"]

        console.log(race)
        jQuery.each(statarray, function(i, val){
            if( race == "Human"){
                console.log("#"+val+"-add");
                $("#"+val+"-add").append("HIII");
                console.log("appended "+val);
            }
            console.log($("#str-add").text());
        });
        console.log($("#str-add").text());
    });
    console.log($("#str-add").text());
</script>
</html>
```

And for the loaded HTML

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td class = "add" id = "str-add"></td>
    <td class = "label">Strength</td>
    <td class = "stat" id = "str"></td>
    <td class = "mod" id = "str-mod"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class = "add" id = "con-add"></td>
    <td class = "label">Constitution</td>
    <td class = "stat" id = "con"></td>
    <td class = "mod" id = "con-mod"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class = "add" id = "dex-add"></td>
    <td class = "label">Dexterity</td>
    <td class = "stat" id = "dex"></td>
    <td class = "mod" id = "dex-mod"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class = "add" id = "int-add"></td>
    <td class = "label">Intelligence</td>
    <td class = "stat" id = "int"></td>
    <td class = "mod" id = "int-mod"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class = "add" id = "wis-add"></td>
    <td class = "label">Wisdom</td>
    <td class = "stat" id = "wis"></td>
    <td class = "mod" id = "wis-mod"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class = "add" id = "cha-add"></td>
    <td class = "label">Charisma</td>
    <td class = "stat" id = "cha"></td>
    <td class = "mod" id = "cha-mod"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: It's what happens when you submit a form, the page reloads, and all changes done with javascript are lost.

Comment: @adeneo i have a question hi type is button not submit does it still submit the form? `<input type = "button" value = "Submit" id = "sub">`

Comment: I don't think it will really put anything. How do you test that `append` is successful?

Comment: @guradio - you're right, missed that, when the type is `button` the form isn't submitted

Comment: @maowtm I tested through making sure the text was there.  console.log($("#str-add").text()); It returned with HIII

Comment: If it helps, it isn't that it isn't getting submitted. I am able to place the race class and stat names.